# Calculating residue

Tags: sequences-and-series, residue-calculus

I really don't know too much about residue or how to calculate it, but just out of curiosity how would I find the residue of $e^{-1/z^2} $ at $ z=0$?
Would it make sense to do so? And would this value have any effect on some series representation around zero? I really don't know too much about any of this so forgive me if these questions are a little off target.

Thanks!

Comment: For that function, just expanding the exponential series $$e^{-1/z^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}z^{-2k}$$ is simple enough (unless you directly see that the residue is $0$ since it's an even function).

Comment: $e^{-1/z^2}=1-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{2!z^4}-\ldots$. Residue is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$, which is $0$.

Comment: @njguliyev Post it as an answer?

Comment: I see, so I find the series and look for the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ which in the case of the function I mentioned is 0. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laurent expansion of the function $e^{-1/z^2}$ is
$$e^{-1/z^2}=1-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{2!z^4}-\ldots$$
$\operatorname{res}_{z=0} e^{-1/z^2}$ is the coefficient of $\frac1z$, which equals $0$.